# Closing connection in order to get remaining queries to run

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Perhaps I'm missing something very obvious here.

My code doesn't seem to work below the 'GET BOOK ID' annotation if I don't close and reopen the connection.

While it does work, it doesn't seem to be an efficient way at all to do this, any suggestions?

```
$AddBook = $conn->prepare("CALL makeBooking((SELECT CustID FROM customer WHERE UserName = '$UserName'), ?, ?, ?, ?, now())");
$AddBook->bind_param('iiis',$PerfID, $NumAdults, $NumChilds, $ColTicket);
if ($AddBook->execute())
{
    //----------------DEDUCT SEATS--------------//
    $SeatDeduction = $conn->prepare("CALL deductSeats($TotalSeats,?)");
    $SeatDeduction->bind_param('i',$PerfID);
    $SeatDeduction->execute();
    mysqli_close($conn);
    require ('connect.php');
    //-----------------GET BOOK ID--------------//
    $getBookID = "CALL getBookByUserName('$UserName')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $getBookID);
    $Output2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $BookID = $Output2['BookID'];
    mysqli_close($conn);
    require ('connect.php'); 
    //-------------------SET COST---------------//
    $setCost = "CALL setBookingPrice($BookID)";
    mysqli_query($conn,$setCost);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    require ('connect.php');
    //-------------------GET COST---------------//
    $getCost = "CALL getCost($BookID)";
    $result6 = mysqli_query($conn,$getCost);
    $Output6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6);
    $Cost = $Output6['TotalCost'];
    mysqli_close($conn);
    require ('connect.php');
    //---------------BOOKING CONFIRM------------//
    $ShowRef = 'Booking Completed<p>Reference Number: <b>' . $BookID . '</b><p>';
    $showCost = 'Total Cost: <b><u>£' . $Cost . '<u><b><br>';
    $Confirm = $ShowRef.$showCost;
}
else
{
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to keep including the `connect.php` file over and over.
Assuming you already included it somewhere at the top since you run `$AddBook->execute()`

See this updated code:

```
$AddBook = $conn->prepare("CALL makeBooking((SELECT CustID FROM customer WHERE UserName = '$UserName'), ?, ?, ?, ?, now())");
$AddBook->bind_param('iiis',$PerfID, $NumAdults, $NumChilds, $ColTicket);
if ($AddBook->execute())
{
    //----------------DEDUCT SEATS--------------//
    $SeatDeduction = $conn->prepare("CALL deductSeats($TotalSeats,?)");
    $SeatDeduction->bind_param('i',$PerfID);
    $SeatDeduction->execute();

    $SeatDeduction->close();
    $conn->next_result();

    // mysqli_close($conn); // remove this
    // require ('connect.php'); // remove this
    //-----------------GET BOOK ID--------------//
    $getBookID = "CALL getBookByUserName('$UserName')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $getBookID);
    $Output2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $BookID = $Output2['BookID'];
    // mysqli_close($conn); remove this
    // require ('connect.php');  remove this
    //-------------------SET COST---------------//
    // ...
    //-------------------GET COST---------------//
    // ...
    //---------------BOOKING CONFIRM------------//
    // ...
}
else
{
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Yes the reason why I have closed and reconnected is because the following queries won't run and I have no idea why

Comment: see this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/14561639/5043552, i believe it will help, notice how after each stored procedure call, the result object is closed, *not* the connection, and your equivalent of `$conn->next_result()` is called

Comment: Aha, I saw this very post and tried this, it gives me this...Call to a member function close() on string

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773694/2-prepared-statements-2-stored-procedures-1-mysqli-connection

Comment: make sure it's not a string but an object, like `$result`

Comment: $conn->next_result(); fixed my issue, thanks once again!